# Synchronise a mobile light database with ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: mobile, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, couchbase, offline

I am building a mobile application targeting iOS, Android and WP with Ionic/Cordova. And using ASP.NET Web API 2 REST APIs backend.

I have the requirement that the mobile application can collect data and synchronise it with the APIs and if the mobile is offline, the sync will happen when it is online. The data size is small and any light DB would do including the localStorage one. The required sync is only needed one way, mobile to APIs. Also, once a record is synchronised, it can be deleted from the mobile.

I was looking at Couchbase mobile, but I found it is a Mobile DB to DB sort of a solution.

**Can you recommend a mobile DB to REST/Web API sync solution?**

Answer (score 0):

With the native Couchbase Mobile solution for [Android](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/index.html)/[iOS](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-ios-app/index.html) coupled with the [REST APIs](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/index.html) you are able to get data from Mobile device to your backend.  Then delete any documents off your device once you get back a 200 status.
For Windows Phone, you can explore using [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) or going with the javascript browser based solution across all platforms since WP is not currently supported.

For the replication or sync to occur when your device is online again, you would require your backend to use Couchbase Server and implement the [replication](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/replication/index.html) class methods in your native mobile app to have the push feature.  Or you can use the REST API with logic detection when you are online again to POST to your backend.